# How to execute and get result of NodeJS promise?

Tags: node.js

```
var Queue = require('bull');

// Init queue
var workQueue = new Queue("workQueue", "redis://pass@ip:6379");

// Add 10 jobs to the queue
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    workQueue.add({msg:i});
}

// Get # of jobs in queue
workQueue.count(); // <-- does not return queue job count
```

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/blob/develop/REFERENCE.md#queuecount), `.count()`

> "Returns a promise that returns the number of jobs in the queue"

If I understand this correctly, a promise is an async process waiting to be executed. So how do I execute this promise and get its result?

Comment: You answered your own question, `count` returns a `promise` so you can't just "print" it: `workQueue.count().then(n => console.log('number of jobs: ' + n))`

Comment: Aha. So `.then()` is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am guessing your requirement correctly, you're doing `queue.count()` to determine if there are pending jobs.

You should do a setInterval() to periodically check, and then take action when nothing's pending:

```
let check = setInterval(()=>{
    workQueue.count().then(_count => {
        if (_count === 0){
            clearInterval(check);
            /* do what you need to do here */
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I'm actually running `.count()` at the start to alert the user to any old jobs that didn't complete during its last run. `.then()` is the piece I was missing.

Comment: Okay. You could also do await then.
`let count = await workQueue.count();`